# ruby change home page to an html file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have an html homepage that I created along with some CSS and JS code. I want to include this to my ruby application as a homepage. In my config/routes.rb I have this:

```
  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  # just remember to delete public/index.html.
  # root :to => 'welcome#index'
  root :to => 'first_controller#index', :as => 'first_controller'
```

and in my `first_controller` I have this:

```
class FirstControllerController < ApplicationController

  def index
        @users = User.all
  end

end
```

Can I create a `def home` method that redirects to my html file?

The `@users = User.all` is code from a book im reading, that teaches you how to build a ruby app, that I modify along hte way to my needs. 
thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
class FirstControllerController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def home
    render :template => "relative/path/from/views", :layout => false
  end

end
```

Also, since it is plain html, you could make rails cache it. Add `caches_page :home` in your controller

Edit: formatting